# Chamada serviço AXIS com C#

Tags: c#, services

Preciso consumir este serviço em uma aplicação C#:

https://tidigital.voegol.com.br/arsys/WSDL/public/ars-tidigital/GOL_Requisicao

Mas não consigo adicionar como referencia no projeto.
Ao tentar fazer dessa forma, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

Hi there, this is an AXIS service!
Perhaps there will be a form for invoking the service here...

Por isso estou tentando fazer a requisição via HttpWebRequest.

```
public class SoapProxy
    {
        private const string userName = "xxxx";
        private const string password = "xxxx";

        public static string ServicoRequisicao(string chamado)
        {
            var _url = "https://tidigital.voegol.com.br/arsys/WSDL/public/ars-tidigital/GOL_Requisicao";
            var _action = "http://tidigital.voegol.com.br/arsys/services/ARService?server=ars-tidigital&webService=GOL_Requisicao"; //https://tidigital.voegol.com.br/arsys/WSDL/public/ars-tidigital/GOL_Requisicao/Lista

            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = RequisicaoSoap(chamado);
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
            InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

            IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);
            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

            string soapResult;
            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return soapResult;
        }


        private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }

        private static XmlDocument RequisicaoSoap(string chamado)
        {
            XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
            //            soapEnvelop.LoadXml(string.Format(@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:urn=""urn:GOL_Requisicao"">
            //   <soapenv:Body>
            //      <urn:Lista>
            //         <urn:Chamado>{0}</urn:Chamado>
            //      </urn:Lista>
            //   </soapenv:Body>
            //</soapenv:Envelope>", chamado));

            soapEnvelop.LoadXml(string.Format(@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:urn=""urn:GOL_Requisicao"">
               <soapenv:Header>
                  <urn:AuthenticationInfo>
                     <urn:userName>{0}</urn:userName>
                     <urn:password>{1}</urn:password>
                  </urn:AuthenticationInfo>
               </soapenv:Header>
               <soapenv:Body>
                  <urn:Lista>
                     <urn:Chamado>{2}</urn:Chamado>
                  </urn:Lista>
               </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>", userName, password, chamado));
            return soapEnvelop;
        }

        private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }
        }
```

Analisando o serviço pelo SOAPUI, ele tem esta estrutura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tento efetuar a chamadado serviço, não estou conseguindo chegar no método "Lista".

O serviço simplesmente esta me devolvendo a estrutura do WSDL inteiro.

Este serviço também não funciona como "Service Reference" conforme descrito pelo Thiago Loureiro

```
golReq.GOL_RequisicaoService req = new golReq.GOL_RequisicaoService();
            golReq.StatusType status = new golReq.StatusType();
            golReq.OutputMapping6Workinfo[] wi = null;
            string reqId = "";

            var x = req.Lista("REQ000000131412", out reqId, out status, out wi);
            return x;
```

Ao executar esse código recebo este erro:

> System.Net.WebException: Falha na solicitação com resposta vazia.

Answer (score 0):

Otavio,
Primeiro no seu projeto vá em References, Add Service Reference
Clique em Advanced

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

clique em Add Web Reference
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Coloque a url e escolha um nome amigável para sua referencia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui chegar no Lista:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Thiago, eu já havia tentado desta maneira. Mas não funcionou. Recebo um outro erro executando desta maneira.

Comment: Qual erro você recebe dessa maneira?

Comment: System.Net.WebException: Falha na solicitação com resposta vazia.